# Very strange! Calling window.location or location.replace redirects to the page, then back again!

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in debug mode, so I can see which page is being hit.

When I call either `window.location` or `window.location.replace(..)` it goes to the page, but then back to the originating page!

How could this be??

The solution was to add:

```
    window.location.replace(...);

    return false;
```

Why does `return false` make this work properly now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this script happened on an `onclick` or `onsubmit` event, then no return or returning `true` will indicate that the browser should take the default action for the link/form.  So, if you had an `onclick` handler like:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" onclick="window.location = 'http://www.yahoo.com/';">
```

Then the browser will go to Yahoo, then see that it should execute the link's other action (navigating to Google).  When you indicate `return false;`, the browser knows not to execute the next/default action.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" onclick="window.location = 'http://www.yahoo.com/'; return false;">
```

So, why does `return false;` make this work?

For any event hander, to return `true` indicates to continue as normal and to return `false` means to stop trying to handle the event ([prevents default handling and stops propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)), though there are [arguments against using `return false;`](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/).

Comment: +1. If the element clicked on had '#' as its `href`, then it'll change location, then go back to the starting page. Returning false stops the default behaviour.