# Page redirection not working in firefox using window.location but working in chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox

I wrote the following code to redirect the user to different pages on click. While the following code works fine in chrome, but it does not work in IE or firefox.

However, when i open the same buttons in new tab, they work just fine. But with single left click they do not work on any browser other than chrome.

I tried variations like, `window.location='url'` and `window.location.assign(url)` and `window.location.href="url"` but to no avail.

Please if someone can help me.

`if (this.href == "http://www.successlabs.pk/download.php") {
                        window.location.href= "http://www.successlabs.pk/download.php";}
else if (this.href == "http://www.successlabs.pk/ContactUs.html") {
                        window.location.href= "http://www.successlabs.pk/ContactUs.html";}`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

this question is over a year old, but this is what worked for me:

```
function gotoPage(_link) {
   var _link = 'http://www.successlabs.pk/download.php';
   window.location(_link);
   return false;
}
```

It's possible that adding the 'return false;' line is what will make it work for you.  [This SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678515/very-strange-calling-window-location-or-location-replace-redirects-to-the-page) explains why.

Answer (score 0):

From the horse's mouth: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

> **Example #1: Navigate to a new page**
>
> Whenever a new value is assigned to the location object, a document
>   will be loaded using the URL as if location.assign() had been called
>   with the modified URL. Note that security settings, like CORS, may
>   prevent this to effectively happen.
>
> ```
> location.assign("http://www.mozilla.org"); // or location =
> "http://www.mozilla.org";
> ```

I have never used `location.href` before only the two examples given above - and they work in all browsers

Comment: `location.assign` does not help either. why does it work just fine when i right click and open it in new tab?